# Disabling strict mode in Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there a way to disable strict mode in Expo?

Currently it is not possible to use Automatic Batching in React 18 in Expo without building the application because it does not work in strict mode.

While testing, I found that the problem with Automatic Batching only occurs when executing asynchronous code.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

let rerender = 0
function App() {
    rerender++
    console.log("rerender",rerender)
    const [stateOne,setStateOne] = useState(null)
    const [stateTwo,setStateTwo] = useState(false)
    const [stateThree,setStateThree] = useState('')
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then(() => {
            setStateOne({});
            setStateTwo(true)
            setStateThree('test');
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <div></div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

In this snippet, Automatic Batching does not work as long as strict mode is enabled.

Comment: Looks like the only current way to get rid of strict mode in Expo is with the `--no-dev` flag as in https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/development-mode/#production-mode